# How to combine lists(first three columns) to generate output shown in last column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

| List1 | List2 | List3 | **output** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAN | TH | ESE | MAN-TH-ESE |
|  |  | PA | MAN-TH-PA |
| PWP | TH | ESE | PWP-TH-ESE |
|  |  | PA | PWP-TH-PA |
|  | PR | ESE | PWP-PR-ESE |
|  |  | PA | PWP-PR-PA |
| MAD | TH | ESE | MAD-TH-ESE |
|  |  | PA | MAD-TH-PA |
|  | PR | ESE | MAD-PR-ESE |
|  |  | PA | MAD-PR-PA |
| ETI | TH | ESE | ETI-TH-ESE |
|  |  | PA | ETI-TH-PA |
| NIS | TH | ESE | NIS-TH-ESE |
|  |  | PA | NIS-TH-PA |
|  | PR | ESE | NIS-PR-ESE |
|  |  | PA | NIS-PR-PA |
| EDP | PR | ESE | EDP-PR-ESE |
|  |  | PA | EDP-PR-PA |
| CAP | PR | ESE | CAP-PR-ESE |
|  |  | PA | CAP-PR-PA |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace empty space by missing values, forward filling them and last join together:

```
df['output'] = df[['List1','List2','List3']].replace('',np.nan).ffill().apply('-'.join, 1)
```

If need join all columns:

```
df['output'] = df.replace('',np.nan).ffill().apply('-'.join, 1)
```

Comment: @user6903964 - Can you explain more?

Comment: List1, List2 and List3 are separate lists obtained from table. if List2 contains only "TH" then each element List1 subject name combine with list2 and list3 2 times for ESE and PA. Some subjects may have TH and PR also.

Comment: @user6903964 - So `List1, List2 and List3 ` are not columns names? What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: sub_name=['MAN', 'PWP','MAD', 'ETI', 'NIS', 'EDP', 'CAP']
head=['TH', 'TH', 'PR', 'TH', 'PR', 'TH', 'TH', 'PR', 'PR', 'PR']
exam=['ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', '
ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA', 'ESE', 'PA'] I got these list extracted from dataframe.